# How to get coordinates from WordPress custom fields to embed Google Maps?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to follow what was said [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91546/pass-custom-fields-values-to-google-maps) but with a few edits. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong with this. Nothing is being displayed. The custom fields are filled obviously too.

The javascript:

```
function initialize() {
    lat = 0;
    long = 0;
    if (typeof my-coordinates !== 'undefined' && my-coordinates.lat && my-coordinates.long) {
        lat = my-coordinates.lat;
        long = my-coordinates.long;
    }
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
```

The HTML:

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../map.js"></script>
</div>
    <div class="googlemap">
    <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 350px; height: 310px;"></div>
    </div>
```

The function:

```
function register_plugin_scripts() {
    global $post;
    $woo_maps_lat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_maps_lat', true);
    $woo_maps_long = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_maps_long', true);

    if( !empty($woo_maps_lat) && !empty($woo_maps_long) ) {
        wp_localize_script('my-coordinates-script', 'my-coordinates', array(
        'lat' => $woo_maps_lat,
        'long' => $woo_maps_long
        ));
    }
} // end register_plugin_scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_scripts' );
```

---

EDIT: I haven't been able to figure this out still. Here's what I got so far.

```
function register_plugin_scripts() {
    global $post;
    $woo_maps_lat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_maps_lat', true);
    $woo_maps_long = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_maps_long', true);

    if( !empty($woo_maps_lat) && !empty($woo_maps_long) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('my_coordinates_script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'http://michaeltieso.com/map/wp-content/plugins/medellin-living-map/map.js');
        wp_localize_script('my_coordinates_script', 'my_coordinates', array(
            'lat' => $woo_maps_lat,
            'long' => $woo_maps_long
        ));
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_scripts' );
```

and for the JS

```
function initialize() {
    lat = 0;
    long = 0;
    if (typeof my_coordinates !== 'undefined' && my_coordinates.lat && my_coordinates.long) {
        lat = my_coordinates.lat;
        long = my_coordinates.long;
    }
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
```

You can view the example here: http://michaeltieso.com/map/hello-world/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the browser console (usually f12) then you'll see some problems:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://michaeltieso.com/map/wp-content/themes/genesishttp:/michaeltieso.com/map/wp-content/plugins/medellin-living-map/map.js?ver=3.5.1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
```

I'm not sure what's up with main.js since it's minified, but `http://michaeltieso.com/map/wp-content/themes/genesishttp:/michaeltieso.com/map/wp-content/plugins/medellin-living-map/map.js?ver=3.5.1` clearly has a problem: it looks like you have a typo in your head element.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://michaeltieso.com/map/wp-content/themes/genesishttp://michaeltieso.com/map/wp-content/plugins/medellin-living-map/map.js?ver=3.5.1"></script>
```

should probably be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://michaeltieso.com/map/wp-content/plugins/medellin-living-map/map.js?ver=3.5.1"></script>
```

so the browser can't find the javascript to execute. Even then, the other error in main.js may be enough to halt JS execution, but definitely fix the map script first.

### EDIT:

Ok, I think I might know what's still wrong. You're initializing the map with this call:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
```

but getElementById will return nothing, since you don't have an element with an ID of googleMap in the document. You're probably intending to target this code:

```
<div class="googlemap">
  <div id="map" style="width: 350px; height: 310px;"></div>
</div>
```

which would require this call:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);
```

So try that out, but a word of warning - using an id like "map" is asking for trouble, since it's so generic. It would be extremely easy to forget you used it once and use it again in a page, and ids should be unique. You might want to use something just a little more specific.

Comment: Thank you for that. I see what I did wrong with map.js. I fixed that but the map still isn't appearing.
Where are you finding main.js?

Comment: It's loaded in the page:`<p class="localmap-line2"><span class="localmap-heading">Comments:</span>
     Comments go here  
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/13/4/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</p>` [Edit: it's added dynamically, presumably by the google maps api, so it won't be in your original code]

Comment: GENIUS! It works! Thank you so much for that. And yes, will definitely be changing the ID of that div.

Answer (score 1):

Put your `initialize` function in a `javascript` file, for example, `my-script.js` and put this file inside your theme folder, like, `themes/yourthemefolder/js/my-script.js` and then in your `functions.php`

```
function register_plugin_scripts() {
    global $post;
    $woo_maps_lat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_maps_lat', true);
    $woo_maps_long = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'woo_maps_long', true);

    if( $woo_maps_lat && $woo_maps_long ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('my-coordinates-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js');
        wp_localize_script('my-coordinates-script', 'my_coordinates', array(
            'lat' => $woo_maps_lat,
            'long' => $woo_maps_long
        ));
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_scripts' );
```

**Important :** The variable name `my-coordinates` shouild be `my_coordinates`, dash (-) is not allowed in `JavaScript` variable name, [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9X5t/).

> IMPORTANT!: wp_localize_script() MUST be called after the script it's
>   being attached to has been enqueued or registered. It doesn't put the
>   localized script in a queue for later scripts.

[Read more on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

Comment: Thank you for that. I already have the javascript in a separate file. I've pasted what you have there with the changes but still can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @MichaelT, check the update, `my-coordinates` shouild be `my_coordinates`, `my-coordinates` is not a valid variable name in JavaScript.

Comment: Haven't been able to figure this out still. I put in the edits on the post to what I have now.